# how to get stats from database tables pyspark?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

```
spark.sql("""SHOW DATABASES""").show()
spark.sql("""SHOW TABLES IN Nbadb""").show()
+---------+
|namespace|
+---------+
|  default|
|    nbadb|
+---------+

+---------+------------+-----------+
|namespace|   tableName|isTemporary|
+---------+------------+-----------+
|    nbadb|       games|      false|
|    nbadb|games_detail|      false|
|    nbadb|     players|      false|
|    nbadb|     ranking|      false|
|    nbadb|       teams|      false|
+---------+------------+-----------+

def show_catalog_stats():


spark.sql("""SHOW DATABASES""").show()
spark.sql("""SHOW TABLES IN Nbadb""").show()
```

here is my code I try to create function which return tableNames and data Count(using spark.sql commands).
how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the dataframe summary methods on pyspark for your use case. Follow the
[Pyspark 3.x Dataframe summary methods](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.summary.html) or [Pyspark 2.x summary methods](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.5/api/python/pyspark.sql.html?highlight=dataframe#pyspark.sql.DataFrame) documentat.

```
df = spark.table("database_name.table_name")

df.summary("count").show(truncate=False)
```

Update:

Getting count summaries for all tables in a Database

```
def get_table_counts(dbname):
    table_names = spark.catalog.listTables(dbname)
    table_values_extracted = [f"{table.database}.{table.name}" for table in table_names]

    for table_name in table_values_extracted:
        print(table_name)
        spark.table(table_name).summary("count").show(truncate=False)
    
    return 0
```

Comment: if the answer works for you, please accept the answer

Comment: I need to take name and count without pass it tableName.just return all table name and count data.

Comment: Do you need the counts of all the tables?

Comment: need to return name of tables and data count

Comment: thanks thats work but how to put it inside def?

Comment: thank mate!!!!!